# Grouping or Counting after a Sum

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle/SQL, I am looking for a way to count the number distinct IDs above or below a specified value following a sum. For example, I need to find how many customers have ordered $1,000 or more in goods last year, regardless of whether it was in one large order or several smaller orders. I don't need to identify each customer specifically, just find the total number of customers over this amount.

So far I am able to find the total of orders with:

`select sum (Order_Amount), Customer_ID
from table.orders_placed
where year = 2013
group by Customer_ID
order by Customer_ID`

I can also expand it doing this:

```
select count (dinstinct Customer_ID)
from(
    select sum (Order_Amount), Customer_ID
    from table.orders_placed
    where year = 2013
    group by Customer_ID
    order by Customer_ID
    )
```

but this just gives me the total number of distinct Customer_ID. Any other argument that I add to try to narrow what the "count" gives me results in an error. How can I specify that I want the total Order_Amount of $1,000 or more?

Comment: I would consider a subquery.

Comment: I hadn't appreciated how similar ORACLE was to MySQL

Comment: Why not use a `HAVING`?

Comment: Did you try giving alias to aggregated column and then use that alias to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (no need to order by in inner query)

```
select count (dinstinct Customer_ID)
from(
   select sum (Order_Amount) total_order_amount, Customer_ID
   from table.orders_placed
   where year = 2013
   group by Customer_ID
) where total_order_amount > 1000
```

OR with Having

```
   select sum (Order_Amount) total_order_amount, Customer_ID
   from table.orders_placed
   where year = 2013
   group by Customer_ID
   having sum(order_amount) > 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HAVING` clause to restrict the results of the grouping:

```
select sum (Order_Amount) as Total, Customer_ID
from table.orders_placed
where year = 2013
group by Customer_ID
having sum (Order_Amount) >= 1000
```

Then you can use this as a subquery to perform your aggregation and filtering.